# DynamoDb scan not working properly

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to fetch items from the dynamoDb. However when I fetch single item using partiton key everything works fine but when I try to fetch all the items in dynamo db using scan I encouter an error. Following is the code what I am trying to do:

```
    public List<PageCmsDomain> getAllPages() {
    DynamoDBUtil dynamoDBUtil = new DynamoDBUtil();
    AmazonDynamoDB dynamoDBClient = dynamoDBUtil.getDynamoDBClient();
    DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(dynamoDBClient);
    List<PageCmsDomain> scanResult = mapper.scan(PageCmsDomain.class, new 
    DynamoDBScanExpression());
    return scanResult;
```

Following error comes when I execute this code:

```
com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMappingException: PageCmsDomain[restrictions]; could not unconvert attribute
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapperTableModel.unconvert(DynamoDBMapperTableModel.java:271)
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.privateMarshallIntoObject(DynamoDBMapper.java:456)
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.marshallIntoObjects(DynamoDBMapper.java:484)
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.PaginatedScanList.<init>(PaginatedScanList.java:64)
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.scan(DynamoDBMapper.java:1458)
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.AbstractDynamoDBMapper.scan(AbstractDynamoDBMapper.java:216)
at com.astro.ott.dynamodb.cmsapi.impl.PageCmsDaoImpl.getAllPages(PageCmsDaoImpl.java:74)
at com.astro.ott.cmsapi.impl.PageCmsGetServiceImpl.getPages(PageCmsGetServiceImpl.java:41)
at com.astro.ott.cms_api.cms_api.PageCmsTestCase.get(PageCmsTestCase.java:81)

Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMappingException: not supported; requires @DynamoDBTyped or @DynamoDBTypeConverted
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardModelFactories$Rules$NotSupported.get(StandardModelFactories.java:660)
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardModelFactories$Rules$NotSupported.get(StandardModelFactories.java:650)
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardModelFactories$AbstractRule.unconvert(StandardModelFactories.java:714)
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardModelFactories$AbstractRule.unconvert(StandardModelFactories.java:691)
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBTypeConverter$DelegateConverter.unconvert(DynamoDBTypeConverter.java:109)
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardTypeConverters$Vector$ToMap.unconvert(StandardTypeConverters.java:433)
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardTypeConverters$Vector$ToMap$1.unconvert(StandardTypeConverters.java:417)
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardTypeConverters$Vector$ToMap$1.unconvert(StandardTypeConverters.java:410)
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBTypeConverter$DelegateConverter.unconvert(DynamoDBTypeConverter.java:109)
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBTypeConverter$NullSafeConverter.unconvert(DynamoDBTypeConverter.java:128)
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBTypeConverter$ExtendedConverter.unconvert(DynamoDBTypeConverter.java:88)
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapperFieldModel.unconvert(DynamoDBMapperFieldModel.java:146)
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapperFieldModel.unconvertAndSet(DynamoDBMapperFieldModel.java:164)
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapperTableModel.unconvert(DynamoDBMapperTableModel.java:267)
... 32
```

And I am using same PageCmsDomain while fetching single item also.

Comment: Do you have any attribute called restrictions in class PageCmsDomain? Could you please show the definition of this attribute? Also,Please check  whether the data is consistent on this attribute.

Comment: Yes I do have restrictions attribute.It is defined as follows
   
   '  @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "restrictions")
 private Map<String, Object> restrictions; '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specified code will work only if `restrictions` field is null or empty map. Otherwise it will throw exception as DynamoDB does not allow to save or fetch objects that have field with **Object type** (even as a generic type, in this case - map's value type Object), instead it should have specific type (e.g. `String, Integer, Map<String, Integer>`).

If `restrictions` map's value type can't be changed to specific one,
you can fix that by adding `DynamoDBTypeConvertedJson` annotation to store serialized value of `restrictions` field:

```
@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "restrictions")
@DynamoDBTypeConvertedJson
private Map<String, Object> restrictions;
```

Another option is to specify your own custom converter class and annotate restrictions field with 
`@DynamoDBTypeConverted(converter = CustomConverter.class)`

Comment: so, I guess it is not solution then. for me it fails when the filed is 'int' type. Like

 MyTable[capacity]; could not unconvert attribute. where capacity is int type